# Remove [tsql] without sequelae?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql), in the tag wiki, includes the warning: **Questions about T-SQL should be tagged appropriately with either [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) or [sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase), and include the version as well.** Well, that's ignored frequently. One-third of the 52,950 uses of [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) violate this rule and have neither [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) nor [sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase) attached. Only 159 of the properly-tagged posts include [sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase). 35,638 posts include [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Thus [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) is being used as a synonym for [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), and doesn't add any value. It does detract from searches, as a proper search will look for both [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql), when one or the other should suffice. [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is definitely more popular than [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) with 242,349 uses (including the 35,638 posts that also use [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql)).

My suggestion (edits could be done with database queries):

1. retag all posts tagged [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) with neither
   [sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase) nor [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) as [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), unless the text inside the
   post contains the word *sybase*. retag the posts with the word
   *sybase* as [sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sybase).
2. eliminate [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql).

Unfortunately, I suppose someone will start using tsql again, but at least this will help--[sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is already more popular than [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) and is often used without the [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) tag, so this will then tag the [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) posts with the proper, and more commonly used tag.

### Method of determining number of posts tagged properly

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT PT.PostId)
FROM PostTags AS PT
LEFT JOIN PostTags AS PT1
  ON PT.PostId = PT1.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags AS T
  ON T.Id = PT.TagId AND T.TagName = 'tsql'
INNER JOIN Tags AS T1
  ON T1.Id = PT1.TagId AND T1.TagName IN('sybase','sql-server')
```

Comment: Will users that are interested in answering tsql questions be helped if that tag is removed from the system? How will they subscribe to questions those experts can answer?

Comment: By using [sql-server] or [sql-server*]. Even now, that tag gets about 4X as many questions, and they're the same category. To do that currently, you'd have to search for both [sql-server*] and [tsql].

Comment: Did some SO database queries. It looks like the best way to find those questions is to ignore [tsql]. Using [sql-server*] returns 300,810 questions. Using [sql-server*] or [tsql] gets 311,054. So the tsql tag isn't a significant contributor to the query.

Comment: T-Sql is *not* a synonym for SQL Server. It's a language that runs on SQL Server. It's possible to write questions purely about T-Sql that don't refer to SQL Server and *vice versa*.

Comment: Then why does the tag wiki for tsql state **Questions about T-SQL should be tagged appropriately with either sql-server or sybase, and include the version as well.**? The wiki states that all tsql tags must be accompanied by a server type tag, which makes sense, since there really are two flavors of tsql--Sybase and Microsoft. On the other hand, there are questions about sql-server that don't concern the database language--though most of those questions are probably better asked on DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

The questions from [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, absolutely.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Definitely.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Maybe not, according to your question—but that's not enough, as I'll get into below.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yup, there's only one meaning.

Finally, [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/6388243) has this to say:

> A tag must **fail *all* of these tests** in order to be considered for burnination. **If it is clear that removing the tag will do more harm than good**, then we should obviously not remove it.

This tag passes 3 of the 4 tests, and above all would be a truly *massive* effort to remove, definitely more than it would be worth.

Comment: Perhaps tags like these should be handled in searches as synonyms for other things--so a person searching tsql would automatically be supplied with posts tagged with either (or both) tsql or sql-server, and similarly for those searching sql-server. My concern is not that the tag is meaningless--it's that two different tags are essentially pointing to the same category of questions. And #3 in **When to burninate** specifically talks about merging synonymous tags. I do agree that this would be a big task.

Comment: @rsjaffe since this tag can't be handled through the synonym system, your idea would require that the devs make changes to elasticsearch, and modding libraries that big is never anything to be done lightly.